# How to support firebase library to sdk 14

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My android project's  min minSdkVersion is   14 and  targetSdkVersion is  28.while  i am trying to add firebase  to this project, from the official doc , it gave an error

**error**
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library 
and it 
Suggest that:
1) **use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14**,
        or 
2)increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,

but i don't want the second option 
(increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16)

Is there any way to solve this problem?
please   help me

this is what i tried

Project-level build.gradle (/build.gradle):

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // Add this line
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
  }
}
```

App-level build.gradle (//build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
  // Add this line
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must support SDK versions less than 16, you will have to back up to a very old version of the Firebase and Play services client libraries.  It is strongly recommended that you target at least version 16, otherwise you will be stuck at these old versions of Google libraries.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_version_102